# How can I find all the computers on a network?

Tags: router, wireless-router

Is there a way to see all computers on a network?

I have a "main" router, a switch connected to that router, and a Tenda WiFi router connected to the switch.
I can see those computers which are connected to the "main" router and the switch, but I can not see those which are connected to the Tenda WiFi router. Why is this?

Comment: Are you saying you can't see computers connected to the switch but can see the switch itself? (I guess it could be a managed switch...) Or is the real problem that you can't see anything connected to the Tenda WiFi router?

Comment: oops my bad. I typed "switch" instead of "Tenda WiFi Router"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Scanning tools

There's a plethora if network scanning tools out there. My two favorites are [nmap](http://nmap.org/) and [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/). For the sake of simplicity, I'll demonstrate using Angry IP Scanner.

Specify the range you want to scan and then crack open the settings:
[image]

I like to run 100 threads to speed things up. You might get some wonky results if you go to high depending on the equipment you're running, so be careful and stay moderate if accuracy is of importance:
[image]

It can be of value to add a few common ports if you're looking for a specific device. I always run 80 and 443 to look for any machines serving HTTP. For me, it's very handy when looking for printers and routers:
[image]

Lastly I like to see only responding hosts:

[image]

### Why can't I see everything?

There's a few caveats to scanning. It's not cut and dry.

- Windows 7 machines do not have ICMP ping enabled by default and may not show up
- Anything behind NAT is going to be "invisible"
- If you absolutely have to find everything, try using an nmap intense scan
- Nothing is guaranteed, you might not find everything

If your second router is performing NAT, which it likely is, you're not going to be able to scan that network from the outside (without some trickery that is beyond my knowledge and use.)

And for what it's worth, nmap is a lot handier when it comes to specifying ranges. For example, I often find myself using 10.0.0-255.1 to find all the routers across my network.

Comment: I've used angryIPscanner for ages & its a handy tool, but recently the installer is being blocked by symantec on our corporate desktops, wireshark & nmap seem to pass symantec ok.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Cain & Abel tool, Netscan and Wireshark (definitely most powerful tool).

links:

http://www.oxid.it/cain.html

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Network-IP-Scanner/Net-Scan.shtml

http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 1):

you can find all of your network devices with many application like [the Dude](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude) or [nmap](http://nmap.org/)

Answer (score 0):

By using nmap.org we can idendified which host is active.  Anytime if you connect to any network, then you can run a quick scan to see who your neighbors are on the network.

Comment: OP probably needs a bit more guidance that what you give.